# Help in identifying a Tolkien parody-ripoff with adult themes

Tags: story-identification, novel, elves, dwarves

Back in the late 70s I remember reading a fantasy novel. Tolkien-themed, though not a ripoff.

Had elves and dwarves and humans, etc. And a lot of fairly adolescent sex.

What I remember is that elves had long bifurcated penises, while dwarves had very much longer penises that they coiled around their abdomens like a belt, and that when unwrapped formed a coil. And that dwarves women were constructed to be able to function only either either male dwarves who wrapped clockwise or who wrapped counterclockwise, but were incompatible with the other.

If I recall correctly, the center of the plot involved the offspring of a dwarves male who managed to impregnate an elvish female, or some other such nonsense.

Comment: Brings to mind the parody Bored of the Rings, with Dildo Bugger.

Comment: … but isn't that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Astra and Flondrix](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1118111) by Seamus Cullen. It was published in 1976 which fits the time you remember reading it.

[image: Astra and Flondrix]

> Astra and Flondrix represents a departure in the field of fantasy an erotic Tolkien. Seamus Cullen, using a humor ranging from the gentle to the ribald, has joined past mythology to a post-atomic age. In doing so, he has created a magical world for adults as unique as the one Richard Adams created for children in Watership Down.The book begins "many years from now," when, in a rude new world built in the atomized ashes of the old, a son is born to Barlocks, the Dark King - a son part mortal and part elf. This son, Flondrix, the product of Barlocks' unheard-of sexual transgressions with an Elvan princess, sets out on a gargantuan quest for both a past and a future, wending his way through neo-medieval kingdoms of dwarves, people, and elves. What the naive Flondrix never realizes is that he holds the future of the world between his thighs.The book's own special apocalypse is reached in the confrontation between the distorted skills of the scientist-sorcerer Kranz and the innocent sensuality of Flondrix and Astra, the daughter of the Elvan King. The a fourth world war - of magic.

I cannot find a copy of the book, but a searchable version is [on Google books here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Astra_and_Flondrix/4AfzAAAAMAAJ?hl=en). I am hesitant to add quotes, but searching the book for *schlong* provides ample evidence this is the book you describe.

One of the reviews on Goodreads says:

> Elvish genitals come in pairs, while Dwarves have a more complex spiral arrangement (on which the male Dwarves spring across the countryside).

Comment: This sounds *spectacularly* bad.

Comment: I remember when it came out. It was readily available and everyone thirsted for more Tolkien, yet *no one* I knew seems to have read it. (And this certainly wasn't because of the sex.) Zero or negative word of mouth.

Comment: I tried reading the Danish translation years back, but it was so badly written that I stopped after a few pages. I think the translation was at least partly to blame.

Comment: Oh my goodness this has made the HNQ! There goes the reputation of the SF Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: That sounds like the one.

Comment: It's like real-life *War of the Sex-Elves*:  https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/tolkien